# Disable Jquery UI Button on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form like so:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form" name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="action" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I am using the latest version of the Jquery UI Button plugin. The value of the submit button MUST be submitted. Is there an easy way to disable the submit button after the form has been submitted, without using additional plugins such as "Lock Submit" - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/LockSubmit ?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think the form won't post the value of the submit button when it is disabled. Is this the problem?

Comment: Yeah - I think the only way of doing it reliably is using Lock Submit but I just wondered if the Jquery UI library catered for this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the disabled property of an element, it won't be submitted. The workaround is to set the disabled property *after* the form is submitted. You can use the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) function with a very short delay:

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // .prop() requires jQuery 1.6 or higher
        $("#form :submit").prop("disabled", true);
    }, 100);
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xggzD/)

Another trick, is to use a trick :) You can wrap the original submit button inside a div and hide it when the form submits.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/4tnjd/)

Comment: I decided to go with the "trick" option as it is basically doing the same thing as "Lock Submit" without the hassle of using their library.

Answer (score 3):

Easy just add type="button" to button attributes
like

```
<button type="button" >not submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean

```
$('#form').submit(function() {$(this).find('input:[type="submit"]').button({disabled:true})});
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').disable();
});
```